# jqgrid - format when editing row

Tags: jqgrid

I use client side library jqGrid. When I display column I use format options  of column like this

```
{ name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 100, align: 'right', sortable: false,
  editable: true,  formatter: 'number',
  formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: ".", decimalPlaces: 2} }
```

So, I format number to use “,” for decimal separator and “.” for thousands separator. But when I edit row this column has numbers formatted like  “.” for decimal separator and “,”for thousands separator. How can I correct this behavior? I would like to have same formats (as in my code) in display and edit mode.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Which kind of row editing you use (inline editing, form editing ...)?

Comment: Does anyone have idea how change format of number when I am in edit mode (Form edit). Even if I include localization file (“grid.locale-de.js”) number in column is formatted like “1.234,22” but on edit form there is “.” For decimal separator which is for users very confusing. And validation of entered value is also recognized as mistake…. Is this behavior bug or am I missing something??